# Angular, ng-init doesn't initialize

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Trying to initial a text box with ng-init but the text box is always blank?

```
<form  ng-app="TheApp" ng-init="email='test@test.com'">
    <div>
        <label>email: </label>
        &nbsp;<input type="text" ng-model="email">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't want to use a controller? If you really don't, try ng-app="". And see how that goes

Comment: I was trying to break it down into the easiest repro

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you're starting your angular correctly. Dropping `="TheApp"` makes this work. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63kzjvwv/).

In your app.js, are you defining your angular module as `TheApp`? i.e. `angular.module('TheApp', [])`

```
<form  ng-app ng-init="email = 'test@test.com'">
<div>
    <label>email: </label>
    &nbsp;<input type="text" ng-model="email">
</div>
</form>
```